# Peta Poco where clause

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, petapoco

I am trying to do this in petapoco

```
var people 
= db.Query<Person>("SELECT * FROM people").Where(p => 
 p.FirstName.Equals("George") && p.LastName.Equals("Clooney")).ToList();
```

the problem is that it gets the entire set of records from the database and then performs the filtration on it. I tried Fetch instead of query, same result.

How do I write the query so that it sends the query to get the filtered results from the database, instead of doing the filtering at the webserver?

Comment: Having just looked at petapoco.. it doesn't have a LINQ provider from what I can see.. so what you're trying to do isn't possible. You have to include your filtering in your query.

Comment: You can use LINQ with PetaPoco you would just do it after you ran the query on the List that was returned by the fetch.

Answer (score 8):

```
var people = db.Fetch<Person>("where firstname = @0 and lastname = @1", 
    "George", "Clooney");
```

or using NPoco (which which is based off PetaPoco) this is also possible

```
var people = db.FetchWhere<Person>(x=>x.FirstName == "George"
    && x.LastName == "Clooney");
```

Comment: That's correct if you're expecting multiple records to be returned. If you expect exactly one record then you should use Single or SingleOrDefault if you expect 1 or none...
var person = db.Single<Person>("where firstname = @0 and lastname = @1", 
    "George", "Clooney");

Comment: Just add the single at the end. It makes no difference. var person = db.Fetch<Person>("where firstname = @0 and lastname = @1", "George", "Clooney").Single();